# Cómo ejecutar y recibir parámetro desde c# console app a c# web app

Tags: c#

Hola tengo una `C# Console aplication` la cual la utilizo para obtener mi `MAC` y por otro lado tengo una `C# Web aplication` desde el cual deseo llamar o ejecutar mi aplicación de consola y obtener el valor de mi MAC.

Se que esto puedo hacerlo directamente desde mi aplicación web pero necesito crear como un "ejecutable" el cual obtenga esa información y así recibirla en mi aplicación web. En síntesis deseo realizar esto

1. aplicación web --> ejecuta aplicación de consola
2. aplicación de consola --> obtiene MAC
3. Aplicación web recibe la MAC obtenida por la aplicación de consola

```
static void Main(string[] args){
    string macAddresses = string.Empty;
    foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
    {
        if (nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
        {
            macAddresses += nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
            break;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(macAddresses);
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

si alguien puede orientarme en como poder ejecutar esta aplicación y recibir el `string` que es la `MAC` se lo agradecería de antemano.

Comment: pero esto en el servidor??? o en el cliente?

Comment: actualmente estoy en el servidor, y necesito que mi aplicación de consola se ejecute en el cliente y así obtener la MAC del cliente y no la del servidor

Comment: para eso, como cliente, deberia bajar tu aplicacion, instalarla y la misma deberia conectarse a una url y mandar esa informacion... eso se entiende? es posible? ah.. y la ejecucion deberia ser controlada por el cliente...

Comment: claro, tenía entendido que era de esa manera, el tema es como enviarle mi .exe, también he estado revisando la forma de ejecutar comandos cmd desde javascript para ejecutar el "getmac" y obtener el output como parámetro, no sé si esa sería una manera más viable que la de hacer que descargue mi .exe ?

Comment: desconozco sobre js y si podrias.. pero si estoy en linux y no tengo instalado el framework como haria? no enviarias el exe, le dirias al usuario que lo baje, supongo...

Comment: Me causa curiosidad,.Cuál es la intención de obtener la MAC del cliente si la aplicación es web?

Comment: resulta que estoy desarrollando una applicación a la cual los usuarios al momento de ingresar debo conocer cuál es el equipo físico desde el que ingresan. por temas de acceso. la relación de esto es: 1 Cta --> N equipos y 1 Equipo  --> 1 Cta... como administrador debo otorgarle acceso desde equipos específicos

Comment: Y son equipos propiedad de una empresa o son propiedad de los usuarios?

Comment: son de prestadores afiliados, pero en la práctica son equipos de usuarios

Comment: Eso me hace pensar que cada usuario tiene un equipo asignado. Es correcto?

Comment: exactamente, pero puede darse la casualidad que el usuario tenga permisos para acceder desde más equipos, por eso la relación 1 Cta --> N equipos

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116323/discussion-between-lobos-and-lucas-munoz).